# Iterate through list of objects & methods using for loop

Tags: java, object, methods, iteration, accumulator

The entirety of the code can be found at the bottom of this post, but the only part that really concerns me is,

```
for(zed = 0; zed<photoes.size(); zed++) {
totesPrice += photoes<zed>.getCost();
totesSize += photoes<zed>.getMegabytes();
totesSpeed = photoes<zed>.getSpeed();
}
```

Ideally the totesPrice, totesSize, and totesSpeed would be the sum of the get methods for the objects stored in the photoes list array.

```
// Import classes for class
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DigitalMain
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    String cont = "Y";
    String heightString,width,bitpsString = "";
    String widthString = "";
    int zed;
    double bitps,pHS,pWS = 0.0;
    double totesSpeed = 0.0;
    double totesPrice = 0.0;
    double totesSize = 0.0;
    DecimalFormat wholeDigits = new DecimalFormat("0");
    DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

    List<DigitalPhoto> photoes = new ArrayList<DigitalPhoto>();
    do
    {
    DigitalPhoto photo = new DigitalPhoto();
    heightString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter height");
    pHS = Double.parseDouble(heightString);
    photo.setHeight(pHS);
    widthString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter width");
    pWS = Double.parseDouble(widthString);
    photo.setWidth(pWS);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Height: " + photo.getHeight() + "\nWidth: " + photo.getWidth() + "\nResolution: " + photo.getResolution() + " DPI\nCompression Ratio: " + photo.getCompression() + "\nRequired Storage: " + dec.format(photo.getKilo()) + " Kilobytes.\nPrice of Scanned Photo: $" + dec.format(photo.getCost()) + " dollars.");
    do
    {
    bitpsString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your internet connection speed in BITS not BYTES please.");
    bitps = Double.parseDouble(bitpsString);
    } while (bitps < 0 && bitps > 99999999);
    photo.setSpeed(bitps);

    for(zed = 0; zed<photoes.size(); zed++) {
    totesPrice += photoes<zed>.getCost();
    totesSize += photoes<zed>.getMegabytes();
    totesSpeed = photoes<zed>.getSpeed();
    }
    cont = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("\nType \'Y\' to try again or anything but \'Y\' to use values.");
    photoes.add(photo);
    } while (cont.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));





    double seconds = transferTime(totesSize, totesSpeed);
    double minutes = seconds / 60;
    double realsec = seconds % 60;

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You will be paying: " + totesPrice + "\nRequired Storage is: " + totesSize + "Required time for transfer is: " + wholeDigits.format(minutes) + " minutes, and " + wholeDigits.format(realsec) + " seconds.");

  }

  public static double transferTime(double totalStorage, double netSpeed) {
    double bits, seconds;
    bits = (totalStorage * 8);
    seconds = (bits / netSpeed);
    return seconds;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think u have to your generics..    [for:each](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)
u can try this ...

```
    for (DigitalPhoto digitalPhoto : photoes) {
        totesPrice += digitalPhoto.getCost();
        totesSize += digitalPhoto.getMegabytes();
        totesSpeed = digitalPhoto.getSpeed();
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(zed = 0; zed<photoes.size(); zed++) 
{
   totesPrice += photoes.get(zed).getCost();
   totesSize += photoes.get(zed).getMegabytes();
   totesSpeed = photoes.get(zed).getSpeed();
}
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an Iterator instead :

```
  Iterator it = photoes.iterator();
  while(it.hasNext())
  {
    DigitalPhoto temp = it.next();
    totesPrice += temp.getCost();
    totesSize += temp.getMegabytes();
    totesSpeed = temp.getSpeed();
  }
```